# Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly Shut Down with ext4-fs error (device sda6)

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, shutdown, ext4

04 in dual boot with Windows 8.1 and i am using it for a long time without any issues. But yesterday while using ubuntu, my system suddenly **black screened** and got the errors as shown in the screenshot. After forcefully shutting down and then rebooting, it is working fine and i am currently working on it(ubuntu) for the last 10 hours without any issues. This(sudden shut down with the same error) has happened 2 times in the last 72 hours. How can i resolve this? Why is this happeing ? I am using Dell Inspiron 3543. Below are the screenshots i took.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWKqe.jpg)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DHS8.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these errors are hard drive errors. The hard drive is failing. You did say you have been using it for a long time. Time to back up all important data and replace the drive.